# SEO AJAX Calls for Google

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, ajax, jquery

I have a working WordPress site that contains a custom navigation and retrieves a page based on title.  So what it looks like is, lets say I have a page called `test` and the user selects `test` on the custom navigation.  The `href` link that is placed would be `#!test`.  Now I am fully using `Ajax` to call the content for `test` and that looks like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/thenewsite/wp-content/plugins/mass/return_body.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data:
        {
            'key_page' : key_page,
            'function' : 'page_grab'
        },
        .....
 });
```

`return_body.php`:

```
$base = 'http://www.massmedicalstorage.com/thenewsite';

if ($fragment = $_GET['_escaped_fragment_']) {

    $page = get_page_by_title($fragment);
    print_r ($page);
    exit;
}

$DBH = createConnection();
$response = array("status" => "ok", "code" => 1, "original_request" => $_POST); // CREATE REQUEST

if($_POST['function'] == 'page_grab')
{
    $page = get_page_by_title($_POST['key_page']);
    $response['data_retrieved'] = $page;

    if($page !== null)
        $response['status'] = "found";

}
```

Now the `Ajax` function than places the content retrieved based on design requested.

So the area that is gray for me is, am I working with `Google` correctly for `SEO` `ajax` purposes?  Am I returning my content correctly in the `_escaped_fragment_` section? Also how do I check to see if google is fetching the `ajax` content?  If I am not properly retrieving a `snapshot` of my `html` how do I do so correctly?

Comment: See the [Google FAQ for WebMasters](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/faq#whentousewhich), and the [Full Specification Here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification).  Google does not use the `_escaped_fragment_` format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the proper meta tag for google to know that you are crawling Ajax based pages.  In essence when google sees your escaped fragment they replace it with a querystring and pull that page instead.   This makes your Ajax page crawlable.  An alternate approach is just to use HTML history api and update the url when you make an ajax call.  This way you dont have too goof around with HashBang / Google & Bing ajax crawling spec.  It 100% works, but html history is the new and better way of doing this, and gets you much cleaner URLS.   Also gives you a great fallback for users who dont have javascript in place because the actual page will load normally.